# Yii Widget Kartik TypeAhead doesn't work

Tags: php, yii, autocomplete, yii2, typeahead

I'm using the TypeAhead widget from kartik for Yii2 (http://demos.krajee.com/widgets#typeahead-basic). I put all code like an example, but it doesn't work. What's wrong?
In the same page, I used also the FileInput widget (http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/fileinput) and it works fine

In resumen, I have:

```
use kartik\typeahead\TypeaheadBasic;
$data = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas'];

<link href="/vendor/kartik-v/yii2-widget-typeahead/assets/css/typeahead.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/vendor/kartik-v/yii2-widget-typeahead/assets/js/typeahead.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<?= $form->field($model, 'field')->widget(TypeaheadBasic::classname(), [
            'data' => $data,
            'pluginOptions' => ['highlight' => true],
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Filter as you type ...'],
        ])->label('Label') ?>
```

Comment: Are there any javascript bug in your page? check it with firebug

Answer (score 0):

Could be you need  a dataset this way

```
  <?= $form->field($model, 'field')->widget(TypeaheadBasic::classname(), [
              //'data' => $data,
              'pluginOptions' => ['highlight' => true],
              'dataset' => [
                              [
                                  'local' => $data,
                                  'limit' => 10
                              ]
                          ],
              'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Filter as you type ...'],

          ])->label('Label') ?>
```